# General Solution to a Differential EQ with complex eigenvalues.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need a little explanation here the general solution is $$x(t)=c_1u(t)+c_2v(t)$$ where $u(t)=e^{\lambda t}(\textbf{a} \cos \mu t-\textbf{b} \sin \mu t$ and $v(t)=e^{\lambda t}(\textbf{a} \sin \mu t +\textbf{b} \cos \mu t)$ I am confused on what happened to the $i$ that is suppose to be in front of $v(t)$ and why it just "goes away". When they were deriving this formula they just go from writing it as $x^{1}(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$ to the general solution which is throwing me off as to what happened to the $i$. Nothing can just disappear in math without reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really disappear.

Note that $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb R$, so if they are solutions of a second degree  ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients, they form a basis of solutions.

The $i$ disappears because usually one is interested in **real** functions.Of course $u+iv$ will also be a solution to the differential equation, just not a real solution. There's probably a hidden assumption that you're only looking for real solutions.

Comment: Ok so there are actually two solutions two the differential equation? One in the complex plane and the other in the real plane?

Comment: @adam And maybe even more! Think about roots of $x^3-1\color{grey}{=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$. There is only solution in $\mathbb R$, there are three in $\mathbb C$ and maybe there's even a possibility of extending $\mathbb C$ further to have more solutions to this equation. Just as long as there are not contradictions, you're free to do anything.

Comment: how can that equation have more than 3 solutions????

Comment: @adam What about if you look at it also as a matrix equation? To give meaning to an equation it is necessary to specify in which realm you're working on.

Comment: Are you referring to Demovires theorem in which use consider the equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: @adam No, not all. Just regular matrices.

Comment: I am not familiar with the technique of solving polynomial equations of a degree higher than 1 as a matrix

Comment: @adam You misunderstood me. Surely you can recognize that the identity matrix $I$ is a root of the equation $X^3-I
=0$. This is what I mean. Of course in this case $1$ is the identity matrix and not the number $1$.